# Python - Adding to 3 lists, row by row

Tags: python, list, loops

Using slices error:

`list_one = cards_18[0::3] # from index 0 to end, add 3
list_two = cards_18[1::3]
list_three = cards_18[2::3]`

Comment: Can you give an exemple of what is `cards_18`? Note that [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is done for this kind of question.

Comment: You shouldn't have the cards in individual variables in the first place. Use a single list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It seems to me that the cards are in a single list, `cards_18`. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way:

```
list_one = cards_18[0::3]
list_two = cards_18[1::3]
list_three = cards_18[2::3]
```

In `[0::3]`, the `0` means start at the first element, the missing value in the middle means go right to the end, and the `3` at the end means use every third element.

Edit: slightly neater, but the same basic idea:

```
splits = 3
lists = [cards_18[i::splits] for i in range(splits)]
list_one, list_two, list_three = lists
```

The third line is not necessary if you can just work with `lists` directly (which will probably end up giving you cleaner code). The first line isn't necessary because you can just substitute the number 3 directly into the two places on the next line that it's used, but using a variable is clearer IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I guess list_one is [0,3,6,9,12,15], list_two is [1,4,7,10,13,16], list_three [2,5,8,11,14,17].

If you don't need to do it row by row:

```
list_one = cards_18[0::3] # from index 0 to end, add 3
list_two = cards_18[1::3]
list_three = cards_18[2::3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, you want to deal the cards between the three lists.

Just loop through `cards_18` using the modulus operator (`%`) to cycle between the lists.

Example:

```
for i, card in enumerate(cards_18):
    if i%3 == 0:
        list_one.append(card)
    if i%3 == 1:
        list_two.append(card)
    if i%3 == 2:
        list_three.append(card)
```

Comment: Why enumerate ?

Comment: @timburnt enumerating is an easy way of accessing the index of the element in the for loop, you could alternatively use `cards_18.index(card)` to get the current index.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to deal every third card to each column, you could do

```
for i in range(0,18,3):
    list_one.append(cards_18[i])
    list_two.append(cards_18[i+1])
    list_three.append(cards_18[i+2])
```

The range will consist of the integers between 0 and 18 (excluding 18 itself) with a step of 3, so 0, 3, 6, ... 15

You could also use slices:

```
list_one = cards_18[0::3]
list_two = cards_18[1::3]
list_three = cards_18[2::3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify by using slices:

```
list_one = cards_18[:2]
list_two = cards_18[2:4]
list_three = cards_18[4:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you want?

```
list_one = [card for (i, card) in enumerate(cards_18) if i % 3 == 0]
list_two = [card for (i, card) in enumerate(cards_18) if i % 3 == 1]
list_three = [card for (i, card) in enumerate(cards_18) if i % 3 == 2]
```

This uses the fact that the result of the "modulo 3" operation will cycle between 0, 1 and 2 when applied to successive integers.

`enumerate` will generate the indices of the cards in the list along with the cards themselves.

[List comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) enable this kind of short notation.